# Is it possible to integrate Number Picker into a Angular web project?

Tags: angular, angular-material

After the decision to change all the numerical inputs of my website for something similar to the components of a roulette number selector, I wonder if it is possible to add something like Numbers Pickers used in mobile development.

[image: My idea about it...]

The development I am working on would be like the following [example.](https://github.com/JulioRodriguezR/Forms-Reactive-assignment)

Comment: Try with `input type="number"`

Comment: @AdritaSharma That depends on browser support and it won't necessarily display like the slot-machine-wheel look you get on iOS for `<select>` elements.

Comment: Its definitely possible to create custom angular component which resemble all functionality of input type 'number' but having custom template(view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can play with hammer and use swipe or using a cdk DragDropModule.

A attempt is has some like

```
<div #picker class="gesture__zone">
    <div #inner>
        <div class="dragZone" cdkDrag cdkDragLockAxis="y" (cdkDragEnded)="onDrop($event)" >
        </div>
        <div #d class="item" [ngClass]="{'selected':i==value}" 
            *ngFor="let item of items;let i=index"
            (click)="value=i;move(i)">
            {{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See that I need "picker", "inner" and "item" as reference variable. This allow us get them in a ViewChild and have his measure

```
  @ViewChild("d", { static: false, read: ElementRef }) item;
  @ViewChild("picker", { static: false, read: ElementRef }) picker;
  @ViewChild("inner", { static: false, read: ElementRef }) inner;
```

(I make that a click also change the value because I find difficult make a "drag")

If our .css is like

```
.gesture__zone {
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 4rem;
  width:3rem;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.item
{
  padding:.5rem 0;
  opacity:.3;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:1rem;
  background-color:white;
}
.item.selected
{
  opacity:1;
}
.dragZone
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

we can play with onDrop event -really when you end of drag-

```
  onDrop(event)
  {
    const oldValue = this.value;
    if (event.distance.y > 40 && this.value > 0) 
    {
      if (event.distance.y>100 && this.value>2)
          this.value-=2
      else
      this.value--;
    }
    if (event.distance.y < -40 && this.value < this.items.length - 1) 
    {
      if (event.distance.y<-100 && this.value<this.items.length - 2)
          this.value+=2
      else
      this.value++;
    }


    if (oldValue != this.value) {
      this.move(this.value)
    }
    //this three lines of code make the "zone" return o the initial position
    event.source.element.nativeElement.style.transform = 'none' 
    const source: any = event.source
    source._passiveTransform = { x: 0, y: 0 } 
  }
```

The "move" make a little animation

```
  move(value)
  {
    if (!this.picker || !this.item)
    return;
      const marginInit =
        this.picker.nativeElement.clientHeight / 2 -
        1 * this.item.nativeElement.clientHeight;
      const offset =
        marginInit - value * this.item.nativeElement.clientHeight;
      const myAnimation = this.builder.build([
        animate(this.timing, style({ marginTop: offset + "px" }))
      ]);
      this.player = myAnimation.create(this.inner.nativeElement);
      this.player.play();
      this.onChange(this.items[value])
  }
```

In the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ksvnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnumber-picker.component.ts) I make a custom control component implements ControlValueAccessor. I hope this give you an idea to how make a number-picker